# Freetype Exception thrown: read access violation. face was nullptr

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, freetype

''' FT_Face face = nullptr;;

```
FT_GlyphSlot g = face->glyph;
FT_Library ft;
if (FT_Init_FreeType(&ft))
    std::cout << "ERROR::FREETYPE: Could not init FreeType Library" <<
    std::endl;

if (FT_New_Face(ft, "fonts/arial.ttf", 0, &face))
    std::cout << "ERROR::FREETYPE: Failed to load font" << std::endl;
FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes(face, 0, 48);
if (FT_Load_Char(face, 'X', FT_LOAD_RENDER))
    std::cout << "ERROR::FREETYTPE: Failed to load Glyph" << std::en '''
```

When I compile the program, I get this error. "Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation.face was nullptr."

Comment: Make sure you don't dereference `face` when it is `nullptr`?

Comment: **nullptr** gives an error without

Comment: I get this error when nullptr is not "uninitialized local variable 'face' used"

Comment: Have you initialized `face`? If not, then also make sure that it is initialized or it points to an object of the appropriate type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **problem**(mentioned error) is that somewhere in your program you're dereferencing `face` when it is `nullptr` which leads to undefined behavior.

To **solve** this add a check to see if `face` is nullptr or not before dereferencing it as shown below:

```
//go inside the if block only if face is not nullptr
if(face !=nullptr)
{
    //you can safely dereference face here
}
//otherwise print a message to the console
else 
{
    //at this point face is nullptr so don't dereference it at this point
    std::cout<<"cannot dereference face "<<std::endl;
    
}
```

Additionally make sure(if not already) that `face` is initialized i.e., it points to an object of appropriate type.

Comment: Thank you, I found such a solution to my problem `T_New_Face(ft, "fonts/arial.ttf", 0, &face)` but I get a different error, thanks anyway